# Diferença entre .NET Framework para Entity Framework

Tags: .net, entity-framework

Tenho um projeto Asp.Net MVC que ao clicar em propriedades é exibida a seguinte informação:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ao abrir o arquivo `packages.config` pude ver essa outra informação:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Afinal, o que seria exatamente o **Target framework**? Qual sua função? Altera-lo pode causar problemas na aplicação ou no servidor? Quais as desvantagens de estar desatualizado?

Qual a relação entre o **Entity Framework** e o **Target framework**? Qual a dependência entre eles? Atualizar um pode afetar o outro? Posso usar uma versão mais recente do EF em uma aplicação com o Framework antigo?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Afinal, o que seria exatamente o *Target framework*?

É a versão do *framework* .NET para o projeto inteiro. Versões mais recentes possuem mais recursos, mais funcionalidades, e a especificação das linguagens, como C#, se torna mais avançada.

> Qual sua função?

O *framework* é o conjunto de ferramentas implementado pela Microsoft. Basicamente, todas as classes não-primitivas fazem parte dele.

> Altera-lo pode causar problemas na aplicação ou no servidor?

Depende. Alterar para uma versão antiga pode sim causar problemas. Alterar para uma versão nova, dificilmente, salvo raras exceções, mas cujas exceções são devidamente documentadas na Internet.

> Quais as desvantagens de estar desatualizado?

Várias, eu diria. Recursos novos saem com alguma constância. A programação assíncrona, por exemplo, não existe nativamente na versão 4 do .NET. Precisa ser adicionada como um pacote extra. Versões mais novas tendem a ser melhores em desempenho e segurança de dados.

> Qual a relação entre o Entity Framework e o Target framework? Qual a dependência entre eles?

O Entity Framework é dependente da versão do .NET que você está usando. A versão 6, por exemplo, depende do *framework* 4.5 para funcionar.

> Atualizar um pode afetar o outro?

Pode.

Atualizar o .NET para uma versão mais recente não afeta o Entity Framework. Para uma versão mais antiga, pode sim afetar.

Atualizar o Entity Framework pode, em alguns casos, criar uma incompatibilidade com o .NET, mas isso só acontece se a versão do .NET for muito antiga.

> Posso usar uma versão mais recente do EF em uma aplicação com o Framework antigo?

Também depende. [A versão 6 ainda suporta o .NET 4.0](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574253.aspx). Veja este link para mais informações.

Answer (score 7):

Jedaias, a cada evolução do *Framework*, ele trás novas funcionalidades, por exemplo, o 4.5 introduziou o `async` e o `await` e o `Entity Framework 6` faz uso deles através do [`Async Query & Save`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj819165). Então se deseja fazer uso das consultas assíncronas com o `EF`, terá de atualizar o *Framework*, caso contrário poderá continuar com a versão `4.0`.

Por um outro lado, se o `servidor`/`máquina` onde vai ser executado a sua aplicação suporta uma versão mais recente do *Framework*, deve ser relativamente tranquilo fazer migrações do `2.0 -> 3.5` ou do `4.0 -> 4.5` (ou até mesmo para o `4.6.1`), afinal o *Framework* evoluiu de forma incremental e manteve compatibilidade com versões anteriores.

Por um outro lado, o `Entity Framework` sofreu uma restruturação do `EF4` para o `EF5`, houve a mudança de algums `Namespaces`, então você terá de fazer alguns ajustes manuais nos seus `using`, assim como no seu `web.config`. Se fizer a atualização usando o [`NuGet`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework), boa parte destas adaptações será feita automaticamente.